# opencv and python how croped circle area only

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to circle shape crop using only a point to the center. What is the easiest way of doing this?Thanks my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.circle(img,(312,237), 63, (0,0,0),2)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just to make it clear the resulting image will always be a rectangle with the circle. Will the rectangle be of the same size of the source image? or will it be of the size of the diameter of the circle? Ideally you create a mask and copy the image using the mask (so only the circle)

Comment: i need the rectangle with size of the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Suppose center of the circle is `(a1,b1)` and radius is `r`. Then cropping coordinates would be `[ a1-r:a1+r , b1-r:b1+r ]`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('lenna.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
a1=256
b1=256
r=63
cv2.circle(img,(a1,b1), r, (0,0,0),2)
result = img[a1-r:a1+r,b1-r:b1+r]
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the code only works while x and y are equal but not working when changing x and y coordinates

Comment: Swap x and y coordinates. Maybe you are doing the wrong way. In opencv First coordinate is y and second coordinate is x.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can crop the circle from this script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('test2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
x=256
y=256
r=63
# crop image as a square
img = img[y:y+r*2, x:x+r*2]
# create a mask
mask = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), 0, dtype=np.uint8) 
# create circle mask, center, radius, fill color, size of the border
cv2.circle(mask,(r,r), r, (255,255,255),-1)
# get only the inside pixels
fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask)

mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
background = np.full(img.shape, 255, dtype=np.uint8)
bk = cv2.bitwise_or(background, background, mask=mask)
final = cv2.bitwise_or(fg, bk)
cv2.imshow('image',final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```